# How to return to previous search page without being asked to Confirm Form Re-submission and keeping the results on ASP.NET classic Web-forms with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm doing a project for school and i have this page with some search results.
When i go back to the search results page, the browser asks to "Confirm Form Re-submission" and i would like to avoid this.

I haven't done nothing so far to solve this issue besides searching the web for a solution and not had not found one.

Browser message:
Confirm Form Re-submission 
This web page requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: When you go *`Back`* from results?

Comment: When i go back to the results page after clicking a result item and seeing it's page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi. Found the solution for my problem.**

So what i did was, stored the value in session, redirect to a loop page and back, and just preform the search on form load. Now i can go back and forth with no problem. Here is the code i used:

Search page:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   Session["searchValue"] = txtSearchValue.Text; 
   Response.Redirect("loopPage.aspx"); 
}
```

Code on LoopPage.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   Response.Redirect("searchPage.aspx"); 
}
```

search page again:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (Session["searchValue"] != null) 
   { 
      ...preform search and create objects to present results...
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in that you are doing a post request, and if the person making use of  your web page refreshes it, it does what it is supposed to do resubmit the post request.

Hence, there is no way of preventing this issue from happening, what you could rather do is changing the way you obtain the values from a post request to get request.

Comment: Hi Brian. I got an ilumination moment right now. I didn't saw how to transform the request from POST into a GET, since i have always to input the search value to get the results. 
But now i was laying in bed, thinking about the problem and solved it!! If the problem is the data input(search value), what i need to do is NOT to input the search value. It must already be there when the page loads. And this way i transform it into a GET as you where saying! :)
So what i did was, store the value in session, redirect to a loop page and back,and i just preform the search on form load. 
Thank you

Comment: Search button:
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["searchValue"] = txtSearchValue.Text;
            Response.Redirect("loopPage.aspx");
        }

Code on LoopPage.aspx:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("searchForm.aspx");

        }

Code on searchForm:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            DAL x = new DAL();
            if (Session["searchValue"] != null)
            {
                 ...search
            }